# Whats wrong with my solution for this counting problem?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

A, B and C are three different speakers among 7 different speakers, scheduled to speak in a rally. What are the number of ways in which A speaks before B and B speaks before C (its not necessary for A, B, C to speak consecutively)?

My solution:

To follow the conditions given in the problem, we fix ABC and then try to fill the remaining 4 speakers in the spaces between A, B, and C.
For A, B, and C there are 4 spots where I can place any of the remaining speakers. 
_A_B_C_

4 choices for speaker D, 4 choices for speaker E, 4 choices for speaker F and 4 chocies for speaker G, for a total of $4^4 = 256$ ways. But I checked the answer and its incorrect.

Is it wrong because I am not counting some arrangements for eg: If I place all 4 DEFG just before A, there are $4!$ ways to arrange them in that position. But I have not counted those. Or are these already considered in my solution?

Also, what would be an easier way to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have seven slots for people to speak.  You can choose three of them for $A,B,C$ in ${7 \choose 3}=35$ ways.  Having done so, the positions of $A,B,C$ are fixed because you are given their relative order.  Then you have $4!$ ways to arrange the others, so the answer is $35 \cdot 24=840$

Comment: Thanks. But what is wrong with my solution? Which arrangements have I missed?

Comment: First, you missed the selection of when $A,B,C$ speak.  Second, arranging $D,E,F,G$ is $4!$, not $4^4$ because each can speak only once.